# Why are my text boxes different heights (CSS)?

Tags: css

My CSS code:

```
#nav { width:400px; text-align:center; }
#nav span { 
    display:block-inline;
    margin:0 2px;
    padding:2px 12px;
    height:21px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:2px; 
    -moz-border-radius:2px; 
    -webkit-border-radius:2px; 
    text-align:center;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
  <p id="nav">
    <span style="float:left;">previous</span>
    <span>back</span>
    <span>random</span>
    <span style="float:right;">next</span>
  </p>
```

This should give me 4 text boxes the same height, but what I get is this:

[image]

They're correctly top-aligned, but the "previous" and "next" boxes are higher than defined in the CSS. Any idea why that is? (I don't have any CSS specific to floats.)

Comment: as srekoble says in his answer.. You have written the display wrong. It's `display:inline-block` instead of `display:block-inline`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should apply `display: inline-block;` instead of display: block-inline

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/c9br2/1/